# Multiple database on one server or single databases on virtual servers

Tags: sql-server, hosting, shared-hosting

I need to work with multiple databases, and for each database there will be a program which is using that. There is the question, which option is good for performance?

- Creating multiple database on one server, one instance
- For each program and database, create a virtual machine and work on it

Answer (score 1):

Think of it this way.

Sql Server Instance only uses x amount of disk space and y amount of RAM.  a

Sql Server instance per VM will use x, y and then additional RAM and diskspace for the VM lets call those p and r and make n stand for the number of vms.

So for option one your total cost would be x & y

For option 2 your total cost would be x, y, n*p, n*r.

Answer (score 1):

On a single machine, multiple databases on one machine will pretty much always outperform single databases each on multiple VMs on the same machine.

Wow, that was hard to say :-/

The reason a singleton instance will outperform multiple VMs on the same machine is because:

1. You're not paying the virtualization penalty,
2. You're not having to keep multiple copies of the OS running,
3. You're able to share memory use between databases, and
4. Each DB consumes exactly the resources they need; no more and no less.

Various VM technologies work to mitigate those issues (memory ballooning, e.g.), but there is still some penalty for doing it this way.

The big advantage to VMs in this regard is scaling; once a DB is on a VM, moving that VM to a second machine is trivial (and another to a third, etc).  Plus you get snapshotting (which is your absolute bestest friend evar).

The question you must ask yourself then is what your actual scaling and cost requirements are (and what the relative activity of your databases will be).  My guess, unless you've got some really weird requirements, is that your ideal solution should be:

1. Run one database server on a single VM
2. Make very sure to centralize your connect strings someplace where they're easy to change in case you need to break them out.

In general, the base VM penalty is worth paying IMO because you get snapshotting and hardware agnosticism and portability (I personally rarely run anything on bare metal anymore; it's all VMs or containers).  Beyond that, it's easy enough to shard data if need be, so the penalty incurred by the multiple OSes and stacks isn't worth it IMO.

Comment: so are you for it or against it?  good points and well written but your last 2 statements seem to contradict eachother

Comment: Run multiple DBs on a single VM--best of both worlds.

Comment: Not a terrible solution but if pure performance my vote is still on 1 server, much less disk space requirements.  For scale ability and flexibility especially if dbs are small I like your direction.  lots of other parts that neither of us know at this point. cheers

Comment: Agreed that we don't know, but IME it's rare that the VM benefit is outweighed by the costs (and this is coming from a guy who put together manufacturing for 500,000 purpose-built appliances). One VM, many DBs on it is a good compromise.